# How to launch the WSL Ubuntu "Console" from the command line

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-store

I'm struggling to launch the WSL "Ubuntu 20.04" Store App (or any Store App, really) from the command-line (e.g. PowerShell or CMD).

When I run Ubuntu 20.04 from the Start Menu, it launches in a window with the Ubuntu icon and the correct window title ("Ubuntu 20.04 LTS").  I'd like to get that same application window when launched from the command-line.

I've searched quite a bit, and found [this page](https://www.mrlacey.com/2017/01/launch-store-installed-app-from-command.html) that references `start shell:AppsFolder\{folder}!App` (e.g. `start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`), but I haven't been able to make that work for the Ubuntu Store App.  It seems a bit convoluted to me -- Is there an easier way?  And if not, how does that work for Ubuntu?

I'm familiar with the `wsl` command, but if I run `wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04` from the Start Menu, the resulting window has the generic WSL/Linux/Penguin icon instead of the Ubuntu icon.  The window title is also `C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe` instead of "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS."

If I run the same `wsl` command from CMD, it still has the CMD icon.

Perhaps I could use the DOS/CMD `TITLE` command, but I'd like to just have a command I can use to launch the Store app.  Is this possible?

By contrast, "normal" `.exe` Windows apps can be launched from CMD or PowerShell quite easily.

I'd be really happy with a solution for Ubuntu WSL, but also if there is simple (and notably, *programmable*) way to run *all* Windows Store Apps, that would be great.

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  Start, WSL, wait for it to start, kex --esm --ip is , password and the WSL machine starts.  Seems straightforward to me.

Comment: Note: a) from the console, and b) programmable. "kex --esm --ip is
kex : The term 'kex' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: You *could* go through [all this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/starting-windows-10-store-app-from-the-command/836354c5-b5af-4d6c-b414-80e40ed14675) or without even researching the answer, I am guessing that you could use the [System Internals Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see what command line the thingy you want was launched with.  On the other hand, you *could use* the method you and I are bickering about in another post and use a windows shortcut.

Comment: I would happily use such a system for this if I could (I don't have a problem with you using your system as such, it's just that creating and maintaining that folder is so *manual* i.e. not easy to apply in a general way when I sit down at a new system etc), but even that doesn't work for me here as such, because I have to then *manually* create a copy of the shortcut to the Ubuntu WSL (unless you can see a way for me to target the Ubuntu WSL shortcut on the Start menu?). Windows Store App links are a really frustrating and overly awkward feature in Windows 10 in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for that link by the way, unfortunately, it goes back to the position of having to manually create a shortcut to the Windows Store App (at step 4) before we then target *that shortcut* from the command line. Why oh why is it so hard to just target a Windows Store App from the command line <sigh>. Hopefully someone somewhere has discovered how to do this.

Comment: By launching "from the command line", do you mean from CMD, PowerShell, or both?

Comment: "that's fine, but that is different from launching the Windows Store App." - You are actually mistaken.

Comment: Either would be great. I am on a Cmd or PowerShell console, and I want to pop open an Ubuntu WSL. I don't want it to consume the current console (which is the default behaviour of `wsl` and I don't want it to open in a kind of tacky cmd window (which happens if I do `start wsl.exe` where you get this window that says "C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe" and a generic penguin icon instead of an Ubuntu icon). It's really strange to me that there seems to be no way to just invoke a "open up a WSL session for the distro of my choice with the correct title and icon"...

Comment: I'm completely not mistaken Ramhound. I challenge you to invoke the opening of an Ubuntu WSL session with the Ubuntu icon and a title that says 'Ubuntu 20.04 LTS' (as it opens when you press the Ubuntu Start menu shortcut) from the command line. I'm absolutely not mistake here. So far, no one has been able to demonstrate such a thing. Can you? I would simply like you to *prove* that I am mistaken, or would you like to concede that I am not mistaken?

Comment: @YorSubs Hopefully you will accept some constructive criticism.  Your use of hyperbole in your questions ("ludicrous") and answers ("relic") may turn some folks off and discourage careful reading of the rest of the question.  Also, to be honest, your original question lacks some clarity, details, and readability.  If you don't mind, I'll try to do some edits on it to improve it (since I seem to have understood what you are asking).  You are free to roll these back or make additional edits if you wish.

Comment: That's fine, I accept that. I know I was a little *salty* this evening, and indeed, my question here could be more tightly worded (I really do think that UWP issues like this are an unnecessarily complex constructs, it's very confusing to me that they created them in such a hard to manipulate way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing this as a separate answer since, as you've noticed, App Execution Aliases (from my other answer) aren't created by all WSL distributions.

The page that you came across on how to use `start shell:/AppsFolder...` is on the right track, but misses a key point -- The `!App` at the end works for *most* but not all UWP/Store apps.  I actually came across this last year when I was trying to back up my Minecraft Dungeons progress, oddly enough ...

The actual syntax is:

```
start shell:AppsFolder\PackageFamilyName!AppId
```

`PackageFamilyName` typically matches the directory name in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps`, but that directory is not typically readable unless you have elevated your permissions via UAC.

And `AppId` is the real challenge to find.  It's defined in the XML manifest for the package.  And it can be whatever the developer wants it to be.  Most do use `App`, but there are (especially for WSL, it seems) exceptions.

Here's a PowerShell snippet to run through all of your user's Appx packages (Store-installed as well as those that come with Windows) along with a few "system" packages:

```
Get-AppxPackage | ForEach-Object {
  $packageFamilyName = $_.PackageFamilyName
  $packageManifest = Get-AppxPackageManifest $_
  $displayName = $packageManifest.Package.Properties.DisplayName
  $appId = $packageManifest.Package.Applications.Application.Id

  Write-Output "${displayName}: ${packageFamilyName}!${appId}"
}
```

- `Get-AppxPackage`: Enumerate the installed packages
- `$_.PackageFamilyName`: Should match the directory name in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` for most non-system packages
- `Get-AppxPackageManifest` returns the XML package manifest for the app
- Then we get the `DisplayName` and `AppId` properties by traversing the XMLDocument as PowerShell/.Net properties.

You should be able to use the resulting output with the `start` (CMD) or `Start-Process` (PowerShell) a la:

```
start-process shell:AppsFolder\36828agowa338.AlpineWSL_my43bytk1c4nr!alpinewsl
```

But do, of course, check *your* actual output from the above `Get-AppxPackage` test above, since the Family name can change based on the Store release, I believe.

For me, this launched a separate Windows Console with Alpine, with the Alpine logo and title.

Comment: This is perfect. Indeed, it was after finding that `!App` failed for Ubuntu and trying to find the AppId's that I posted my question. Your snippet here to derive the correct string is ideal, unlocking all Windows Store Apps to start from the console (this was what I was hoping for from the searches that I made, but they all proposed clunky manual solutions while this works for every UWP app).

Comment: One minor thing: `$appId` is actually an array. I knew this previously from reading some of the web pages I searched, but one Windows Store App can have multiple associated applications, and you can see this explicitly for the base system `ms-resource://microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps` which contains "Mail", "Calendar", and "ManageAccounts", so for complete automation, we would also have to split up the `$packageManifest.Package.Applications.Application.Id` array, but your answer gives me everything I need to manipulate these objects. 

Answer (score 6):

*Short answer:*

From CMD or PowerShell:

```
start ubuntu.exe
```

If `start` isn't aliased under PowerShell, try:

```
start-process ubuntu.exe
```

*More detail:*

`ubuntu.exe` is the "App Execution Alias" for the "Ubuntu" app installed from the Microsoft Store, although it's possible that it could also be:

- `ubuntu2004.exe`:  If you installed the "versioned" "Ubuntu 20.04" from the Store
- `ubuntu1804.exe`:  If you installed the "versioned" "Ubuntu 18.04"
- And I'll assume that you don't still have the deprecated 16.04 version around.

You can see this by going to *Manage app execution aliases* in Windows Settings.  Many Store apps include a "fake `.exe`" that is designed to launch the Store app.  You can disable this, but I'm assuming it's enabled.  If not, enable it, of course.

When you run Ubuntu from the Start Menu, it is, of course, running the Store app.  This app runs WSL in the legacy Windows Console, and does a couple of additional things such as set the application icon and font.  That's pretty much the only difference than I can find from running it from the command-line.

When you run `ubuntu.exe` (or one of the other WSL app execution aliases) from the command-line, it is started *in* the current terminal.  It's the same as typing `ipconfig.exe`, for instance.  It retains the current characteristics of the "owning" terminal (started by CMD or PowerShell) -- Same app icon, same fonts, etc.

When run with the `start` (CMD) or `Start-Process` (PowerShell) command, it starts a separate process in Windows (rather than as a subprocess of the current shell).  Windows launches it in a new terminal (Windows Console by default), and presumably, WSL does some magic to say "if I'm the owner of the terminal, then set the icon and font".

Comment: Sadly, I get errors when I do this on both Cmd or PowerShell. On Cmd, it says "Windows cannot find ubuntu.exe" and from PowerShell, `start` is not allowed, and `ubuntu.exe` is not found if I run it alone. Where is that `ubuntu.exe` binary located on your system?

Comment: @YorSubs It could be different (which was in my edited answer that I'm working on).  Search for "App Execution Alias" in the Start menu.  See what the execution alias is for your Ubuntu Store App.

Comment: It says `ubuntu2004.exe` in there, so I'm trying that ... well, that's amazing, it works *perfectly*. This is very interesting indeed, as I don't know if you saw the link in my original question, but the methods on the internet to invoke a Windows Store App are incredibly convoluted and gnarly. From PowerShell, I see that I can also do `cmd.exe /c start ubuntu2004.exe`. I wonder if there is a way on the command line to list out the currently defined "App Execution Alias". I guess this must be in the registry somewhere.

Comment: @YorSubs Right, `ubuntu2004.exe` is an alternative in my (still in process) answer, but most installations are just `ubuntu.exe`.  Look for the full post in a few minutes, then I'll look at the App Execution Alias question :-)

Comment: Reading the comments on this page, I see that there are still significant issues with invoking UWP apps, and I see that, unfortunately, there are no "App Execution Aliases" for my other distros (CentoOS and Alpine) so I still have no way to invoke those, but for Ubuntu, it seems that the App Execution Alias is always created at least.
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-app-execution-aliases-windows-10

Comment: @YorSubs Ultimately, I'd recommend that you try Windows Terminal (also installed from the Store).  It is the Microsoft replacement for the legacy Windows Console.  It's open-source and under active development and includes *many* more features than Windows Console that you get when you run your WSL distros now.  It will automatically detect and create profiles for each installed WSL distro.  While you can't change the app icon (that I know of), you can set custom background images (and Window titles) for each WSL instance.

Comment: Agree that Windows Terminal is better for most things, but it's sometimes nice to have Linux separate from my PowerShell windows etc. I always knew that `wt.exe` was an option to invoke Windows Terminal, but I never knew that it was also one of these "App Execution Aliases" things (I was never aware of these before now).

Comment: Part of why I wanted this also was as a way to perfectly reboot my instance of WSL (due to its lack of `systemd`). Unfortunately, "App Execution Aliases" don't exist for all distros (though works perfectly for Ubuntu). For now, I'll have to retain my custom `reboot` script which should reboot any distro:   `alias reboot='cd /mnt/c/ && cmd.exe /c start "Rebooting WSL ..." cmd /c "timeout 5 && title "$WSL_DISTRO_NAME" && wsl.exe -d $WSL_DISTRO_NAME" && wsl.exe --terminate $WSL_DISTRO_NAME'`

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed ubuntu 2024 then just type `ubuntu2024` and hit enter in the command window. It logs into ubuntu in the same command window.